# Nginx can't serve React build

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I can't serve `/admin` page files. Going `/admin` path, NGINX is returning only `index.html`.
Also on paths `/admin/js/chunk.js` and `/admin/css/chunk.css` NGINX is returning `index.html` from build.
My react admin app build is on server: `/root/app-admin/frontend/build/`.
Vue.js app build (which is serving properly) is on server: `/root/app/frontend/build/`.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    
    location /admin {
        root /root/app-admin/frontend/build/;
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }

    location /admin/api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_cf_connecting_ip;
    }


    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_cf_connecting_ip;
    }
    location / {
        root /root/app/frontend/build/;
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
}
```

Comment: Try `location /admin/`

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Did you set the `homepage` flag in `package.json` as : `"homepage": "https://yourwebsite.com/admin",` or `"homepage": ".",`? take a look at https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/